# more than one AD User on offline Windows 7 Laptop

Tags: windows-7, cache, active-directory, credentials

I have three guys sharing a laptop in a location where they will not have internet. I know that windows 7 will cache the last users credentials but will it cache the two or three?

What are my options other than creating a local account (which I would prefer not to do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the group policy setting  **Interactive logon: Number of previous logons to cache (in case domain controller is not available)** under GPO_name\Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options

Microsoft mentions that 2 is a good value for this so one user and one admin can login so 4 may be appropriate for you

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852209(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: +1, but you should add to your answer what to change the value to.  Probably 4, allowing the 3 users and and 1 for the admin.